# Where is \rightarrow defined?

Tags: arrows

For LaTeX, where is the math relation `\rightarrow` defined?

I ask because I'm designing my own version of such an arrow, using TikZ (so as to improve upon the arrow character provided by the Lucida Bright fonts, and so `\rightarrow` looks like arrows produced by `tikz-cd`).

Specifically, what I want to see is what scaling is used for the usual `\rightarrow` from text and display styles to script and scriptscript styles.

I failed to find a definition in either `latex.ltx` or `lucidabr.sty`.

Comment: `fontmath.ltx`, line 337. The “scaling” is determined by the font at the main size, as determined by `\DeclareMathSizes` earlier in the same file.

Comment: you will not see any scaling in the definition of right arrow: it is just a character from a font like `a` or `b`, the font size used in various contexts is specified elsewhere as part of the global math layout setup.

Comment: So for a documentclass with default size 10pt, where would I look to find out what font size is used for scriptstyle and scriptscriptstyle? Or is some other mechanism involved and, if so, what?

Comment: as @egreg says, \DeclareMathSizes  sets up the default sizes (although a class or font package might change it)

Comment: `\DeclareMathSizes{\@xpt}{\@xpt}{7}{5}` means that at 10pt text size use 10pt math with 7pt script and 5pt scriptscript, but this is getting a long way off the question as asked about the location of \rightarrow

Comment: All the comments help greatly, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default `\rightarrow` does not define any scaling it is just a character in a font so like `a` or `b` it is justtypeset at the current font size, which is specified elsewhere.

Specifically this is all set up in `fontmath.ltx` (although classes and font packages may change the defaults)

The relevant lines are

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rightarrow}{\mathrel}{symbols}{"21}
```

which says that `\rightarrow` is character hex 21 in the symbols font, and should get relation spacing (like `=`).

and

```
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xpt}{\@xpt}{7}{5}
```

which means that at 10pt text size use 10pt math with 7pt script and 5pt scriptscript fonts.